# Kendo Multiselect with pre determined values

Tags: kendo-ui, promise, kendo-multiselect

I have looked everywhere and cant seem to get this figured out.  My issue..

I have 1 kendo dropdown list and 3 kendo mutliselects.  each selection filters the next object.  Dropdownl => MS1 => MS2 => MS3...

At times, a user may come into this page with a predetermined set of values that need to be selected in the above objects.  1 for the DD and 1+ for the MS.

I can get the dropdown to populate and have the corrected selected item.  I can get the first MS to populate with the correct values but not select the values that are needed (0 values are selected) and the next 2 dont work cause i cant get past the first MS properly.  I feel like I am running into some kind of sync/async issues that I cant wrap my head around.

See code below.  I have included all my data sources, object setups and functions that i felt were relevant (maybe too much).  The important function is prePopulateSelectedValues.  this is the one that gets called to use the values to select the DD list values.  I only included one of the updateLineShopGroupMS (for example) as the other update functions are basically the same.  Right now I am stuck on 2 different versions of code which both provide the same results - a promise and non-promise version which you can see in prePopulateSelectedValues.

Thank you in advance

```
var lineShopGroupDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
serverFiltering: false,
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "/Base/GetLineShopGroupsFilteredByLocationGroup",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: function (e) {
            return {
                LocationGroupId: getDropDownLists("LocationGroupId").value()
            };
        }
    }
}
});

var locationGroupDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/Base/GetLocationGroupNames',
        data: function (e) {
            return {
                LocationGroupId: getDropDownLists("LocationGroupId").value()
            };
        }
    }
}
});

var substationDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/Base/GetSubstationFilteredByLineShopGroup',
        data: function (e) {
            let ids = getMultiSelect("LineShopGroup").value();
            return {
                LineShopIds: ids.toString()
            };
        }
    }
}
});

var circuitDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/Base/GetCircuitFilteredBySubstation',
        data: function (e) {
            let ids = getMultiSelect("Substation").value();
            return {
                SubstationIds: ids.toString()
            };
        }
    }
}
});

function setUpCircuit() {
$("#Circuit").kendoMultiSelect({
    autoBind: false,
    enable: false,
    placeholder: "Select Circuit(s)...",
    dataTextField: "Text",
    dataValueField: "Value",
    dataSource: circuitDataSource,
    filter: "contains",
    change: function () {

        getHiddenCircuitList();
    }
});
}

function setUpSubstation() {
$("#Substation").kendoMultiSelect({
    autoBind: false,
    enable: false,
    dataTextField: "Text",
    dataValueField: "Value",
    placeholder: "Select Substation(s)...",
    dataSource: substationDataSource,
    filter: "contains",
    change: function () {
        if (document.getElementById('Circuit')) {
            updateCircuitMS();
        }
        getHiddenSubstationList();
    }
});
}

function setUpLineShopGroup() {
$("#LineShopGroup").kendoMultiSelect({
    autoBind: false,
    dataTextField: "Text",
    dataValueField: "Value",
    headerTemplate: "<label style='padding-left: 10px;'><input type='checkbox' id='selectAllLineShopGroups'> Select All</label>",
    dataSource: lineShopGroupDataSource,
    placeholder: "Select Line Shop/Group...",
    change: function () {
        if (document.getElementById('Substation')) {
            updateSubstationMS();
        }

        checkAllFlag("LineShopGroup");
        getHiddenLineShopList();
    }
});
}

function setUpLocationGroupId() {
$("#LocationGroupId").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: true,
    dataTextField: "Text",
    dataValueField: "Value",
    optionLabel: "Select Location Group...",
    dataSource: locationGroupDataSource,
    change: function () {
        if (document.getElementById('LineShopGroup')) {
            updateLineShopGroupMS();
        }
    }
});
 }

function prePopulateSelectedValues(locGroupList, lineShopGroupsList, substationList, circuitList) {

if (locGroupList !== "0") {
    var locGrpDD = $('#LocationGroupId').data('kendoDropDownList');
    var lineShopMS;

    $("#LocGroupString").val(locGroupList);
    locGrpDD.value(locGroupList);

    if (document.getElementById('LineShopGroupString')) {
        debugger
        var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            debugger
            resolve(function () {
                updateLineShopGroupMS();
            });
        });

        promise.then(function() {
            //we have our result here
            debugger
            var lineShopMS = $('#LineShopGroup').data('kendoMultiSelect');
            return lineShopMS; //return a promise here again
        }).then(function(result) {
            //handle the final result
            debugger
            $("#LineShopGroupString").val(lineShopGroupsList);
            result.value([lineShopGroupsList]);
        }).catch(function (reason) {
                debugger
        });
    }
    if (document.getElementById("SubstationString")) {
        updateSubstationMS();
        var substationMS = $('#Substation').data('kendoMultiSelect');
        $("#SubstationString").val(substationList);
        substationMS.value(substationList);
    }
    if (document.getElementById("CircuitsString")) {
        updateCircuitMS();
        var circuitMS = $('#Circuit').data('kendoMultiSelect');
        $("#CircuitsString").val(circuitList);
        substationMS.value(circuitList);
    }
}
}

function updateLineShopGroupMS() {
var msObj = getMultiSelect('LineShopGroup');
var ddValue = getDropDownLists('LocationGroupId').value();
if (ddValue !== '') {
    msObj.enable();
    lineShopGroupDataSource.read();
}
else {
    msObj.enable(false);
    msObj.value([]);
}
```

}

Comment: If it's 'too much' setup for an SO question try creating a dojo.telerik.com example. You can even mock up remote data and server responses (https://dojo.telerik.com/help).  Have your question outline the problem and errors and refer to your dojo.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Richard.  Never thought of using the dojo for somethiong like this.  However, I figured it out.  my issues was here...result.value(lineShopGroupsList);  This was submitting a single string of values like this "1,2,3,4,5...".  What i needed was this result.value(lineShopGroupsList.split(','));.  Had to send an array of strings.  Im an idiot.

Comment: More like was, haha. Keep on coding.